# Outline Server Connected but didn't transfer any data

Tags: vpn, centos7

I configured an Outline VPN Server and everything is ok and VPN connected very well but on another VPS I can connect but no data transfer between the server and the user.
how can I check outline logs or possible errors?
also, I flush all iptables rules to make sure there isn't any issue with the firewall

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in Iran, its possible that the data center whom you bought your VPS has been blocked from the Islamic Republic regime.

The solution to your problem is tunneling your traffic from a VPS located in Iran to your destination VPS.

You can use any proxying tool such as haproxy.

[This Github repo](https://github.com/miladrahimi/outline-bridge-server) might be useful.

Comment: That "Solution" might land the OP in jail.

Comment: I don't think so as long as they are not publicly sharing the IP.